# air 3.3+ app running in background on ios 5.1+?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I know this has been asked many times over the web but I cannot find any information on newer AIR runtimes and newer iOS versions?

I see adobe air 3.3 :

> **Enhanced Background behavior for AIR iOS** — Background support now more closely resembles native applications in iOS. In addition to some basic multitasking and background audio support that is already enabled with AIR for iOS, applications may now support location updates and networking in the background, as well as being notified when a background app is about to be suspended by the operating system

[AIR link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4380335#4380335)

And I see iOS 4+ offers support for long running background apps:

> **Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks**
>   For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>   Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
>   Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
>   Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>   Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
>   Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

[iOS link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

So can anybody tell me if indeed AIR apps using AIR 3.3 can run in the background on iOS?

I require an app that will, even if not active, call a webservice and update the sqlite db that the app uses. Can it be done or must I go the native route?

Comment: Excellent question. +1 from me. Especially the thing about apps being notified when they are about to be suspended sounds interesting. From my own experience, once an AIR app goes into the background, no more code is being processed, so I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked partly, you can find all the details in the next url :

[Air iOS Background behavior](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/04/air-ios-background-behavior/)

Keep in mind your app need to work with CPU render mode (!), and that that FPS goes down to 4 while in background mode.